# Is regex in Java anchored by default with both a ^ and $ character?

Tags: java, regex

From my understanding of regular expressions, the string "00###" has to match with "[0-9]", but not with "^[0-9]$". But it doesn't work with Java regexp's.

After some investigating of this problem I found the following information (http://www.wellho.net/solutions/java-regular-expressions-in-java.html):

> It might appear that Java regular
>   expressions are default anchored with
>   both a ^ and $ character.

Can we be sure that this is true for all versions of JDK? And can this mode be turned off (i.e. to disable default anchoring with ^ and $)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As the article you linked to explains, it depends on the function you call. If you want to add ^ and $ by default, use [`String#matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) or [`Matcher#matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches--). If you don't want that, use the [`Matcher#find`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--) method instead.

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Example
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Matches: " + "abc".matches("a+"));

        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("a+").matcher("abc");
        System.out.println("Find: " + matcher.find());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Matches: false
Find: true
```

Comment: This isn't unique to Java, BTW. Python, and I believe also JavaScript, have some regex methods that anchor by default, and others that don't.

Comment: @Laurence: JavaScript's `test()`, `exec()` and `match()` methods all work the same: if you want the match anchored, you have to anchor it yourself.  On the other hand, Python's `match()` method works like Java's `lookingAt()`; the match is anchored to the beginning of the string but not to the end.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, `matches()` always acts as if the regex were anchored at both ends.  To get the traditional behavior, which is to match any substring of the target, you have to use `find()` (as others have already pointed out).   Very few regex tools offer     anything equivalent to Java's `matches()` methods, so your confusion is justified. The only other one I can think of offhand is the [XML Schema](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html) flavor.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [Mr. Byers's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894624/is-regex-in-java-anchored-by-default-with-both-a-and-character/1894630#1894630), note too that [`Matcher#find()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) picks up where its last successful match left off. That only matters for repeated use of a `Matcher` instance, but that's the feature that allows emulation of Perl's `\G` assertion. It's also useful in concert with [`Matcher#usePattern(Pattern)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#usePattern(java.util.regex.Pattern)), where you use one pattern to find some prefix and then swap in a repeating pattern (including `\G`) to loop over repeated matches with `Matcher#find()`.

There's also [`Matcher#lookingAt()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#lookingAt()), which is implicitly bounded at the beginning (`^`) but not at the end. I prefer to think that name was inspired by the Emacs function [`looking-at`](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Search.html).

Comment: Question on find()'s last position: I guess the position is stored in the `Matcher`, and not in the `Pattern`. If I use an `if (pattern.matcher(string).find())` can I get the position via `pattern.matcher(string)` (i.e. does it return the same `Matcher` object, or a new one?) in the if body? If not, is there a solution without creating explicit named `Matcher` objects?

Comment: The `Matcher` instance holds the state, and `Pattern#matcher()` creates a fresh `Matcher` every time.