# Regex for checking if a string is strictly alphanumeric

Tags: java, regex, alphanumeric

How can I check if a string contains only numbers and alphabets ie. is alphanumeric?

Comment: Try this:

  /^[a-z0-9]+$/i

Check [here][1] too 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388996/regex-for-javascript-to-allow-only-alphanumeric

Answer (score 93):

Considering you want to check for ASCII Alphanumeric characters, Try this:
 `"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"`. Use this RegEx in `String.matches(Regex)`, it will return true if the string is alphanumeric, else it will return false.

```
public boolean isAlphaNumeric(String s){
    String pattern= "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$";
    return s.matches(pattern);
}
```

If it will help, read this for more details about regex: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: -1 as this doesn't cover all alphanumberic characters. M42's response is better.

Comment: Poor use of `if`, better would be `return s.matches(pattern)`

Comment: * allow empty string , use + , like this : ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$

Comment: Do you really need to add the boundary matchers (^,$) at the beginning and end?  It seems like `String pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+";`  would behave the same way since + is greedy.

Comment: Need regex to check if string not contain "test" and contain only alphabet and  space. please help

Comment: @krick Yes, you do need the anchors `^, $` for validation regex. Try testing this string `abc@def` at some site like https://regex101.com/ and you'll see why. You are right that `+` is greedy, but that means it will match `abc` and `def` instead of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f` which a lazy `+?` would. Note: [Java's String.matches() will automatically add the `^,$` anchors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894624/is-regex-in-java-anchored-by-default-with-both-a-and-character) if you don't have them, but it's probably a good practice to include them.

Answer (score 28):

In order to be unicode compatible:

```
^[\pL\pN]+$
```

where

```
\pL stands for any letter
\pN stands for any number
```

Comment: Not working. Giving: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Incorrect Unicode property near index 5.

Comment: IntelliJ also suggests `\\p{Alnum}` (but that's in Java 13)

Comment: @Erk I believe that has been around since Java 7: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: @slugmandrew, good to know. I was hedging. Seems there is one as far back as java 6. But not java 5—it doesn't even seem to have a Pattern class.

Comment: Works in Java May 2023.  It's the most concise answer, yet still readable.  (IntelliJ doesn't suggest change.)

Answer (score 17):

It's 2016 or later and things have progressed. This matches Unicode alphanumeric strings:

```
^[\\p{IsAlphabetic}\\p{IsDigit}]+$
```

See [the reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) (section "Classes for Unicode scripts, blocks, categories and binary properties"). There's also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29718900/2535335) that I found helpful.

Answer (score 11):

See the documentation of [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Assuming US-ASCII alphabet (a-z, A-Z), you could use `\p{Alnum}`.

A regex to check that a line contains only such characters is `"^[\\p{Alnum}]*$"`.

That also matches empty string. To exclude empty string: `"^[\\p{Alnum}]+$"`.

Answer (score 5):

Use character classes:

```
^[[:alnum:]]*$
```

Comment: This is the right idea, but [POSIX character class syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes) is [not valid in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), and the question is tagged as Java.  The equivalent Java syntax for your answer is `"^[\\p{Alnum}]*$"`, as mentioned [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11241830/1840078).  (If such tagging is not considered to be sufficiently conspicuous by site guidelines, let me know and I'll add a comment to the question itself. :))

Answer (score 4):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Teststring123");
if(matcher.matches()) {
     // yay! alphanumeric!
}
```

Comment: works flawlessly!

Answer (score 1):

try this [0-9a-zA-Z]+ for `only alpha and num with one char at-least`..

may need modification so test on it

http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(phoneNumber);
if (matcher.matches()) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To consider all Unicode letters and digits, [`Character.isLetterOrDigit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetterOrDigit(int)) can be used. In Java 8, this can be combined with [`String#codePoints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#codePoints--) and [`IntStream#allMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.IntPredicate-).

```
boolean alphanumeric = str.codePoints().allMatch(Character::isLetterOrDigit);
```

Answer (score 1):

To include `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, you can use `\w`.

So `myString.matches("\\w*")`. (`.matches` must match the entire string so `^\\w*$` is not needed. `.find` can match a substring)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score -1):

100% alphanumeric RegEx (it contains only alphanumeric, not even integers & characters, only alphanumeric)

**For example:**

> special char (not allowed)
>   123 (not allowed)
>   asdf (not allowed)
>   1235asdf (allowed)

---

```
String name="^[^<a-zA-Z>]\\d*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\\d]*$";
```

Comment: so `a12` is not alphanumeric ?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to include foreign language letters as well, you can try:

```
String string = "hippopotamus";
if (string.matches("^[\\p{L}0-9']+$")){
    string is alphanumeric do something here...
}
```

Or if you wanted to allow a specific special character, but not any others. For example for <kbd>#</kbd> or <kbd>space</kbd>, you can try:

```
String string = "#somehashtag";
if(string.matches("^[\\p{L}0-9'#]+$")){
    string is alphanumeric plus #, do something here...
}
```

Answer (score -4):

To check if a String is alphanumeric, you can use a method that goes through every character in the string and checks if it is alphanumeric.

```
    public static boolean isAlphaNumeric(String s){
            for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
                    char c = s.charAt(i);
                    if(!Character.isDigit(c) && !Character.isLetter(c))
                            return false;
            }
            return true;
    }
```