# Fastest way to check a string is alphanumeric in Java

Tags: java, performance

What is the fastest way to check that a String contains only alphanumeric characters.

I have a library for processing extremely large data files, that is CPU bound. I am explicitly looking for information about how to improve the performance of the alphanumeric checking process. I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to check than using pre-compiled regular expressions.

Comment: Premature optimization? Benchmark? Profiling?

Comment: @StephenC There is no code to show, I am asking what the _best_ way is.

Comment: @JimGarrison Some people do have a propensity to do premature optimisation, so its good to raise the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241690/regex-for-checking-if-a-string-is-strictly-alphanumeric

Comment: Character.isLetterOrDigit()

Comment: Note that there _is_ an objective way to answer this question using example code that is benchmarked for performance. Don't vote to delete simply because you are not interested in questions about code performance.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I've written the tests that compare using regular expressions (as per other answers) against not using regular expressions. Tests done on a quad core OSX10.8 machine running Java 1.6

Interestingly using regular expressions turns out to be about 5-10 times slower than manually iterating over a string. Furthermore the `isAlphanumeric2()` function is marginally faster than `isAlphanumeric()`. One supports the case where extended Unicode numbers are allowed, and the other is for when only standard ASCII numbers are allowed.

```
public class QuickTest extends TestCase {

    private final int reps = 1000000;

    public void testRegexp() {
        for(int i = 0; i < reps; i++)
            ("ab4r3rgf"+i).matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]");
    }

public void testIsAlphanumeric() {
    for(int i = 0; i < reps; i++)
        isAlphanumeric("ab4r3rgf"+i);
}

public void testIsAlphanumeric2() {
    for(int i = 0; i < reps; i++)
        isAlphanumeric2("ab4r3rgf"+i);
}

    public boolean isAlphanumeric(String str) {
        for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c))
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public boolean isAlphanumeric2(String str) {
        for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            if (c < 0x30 || (c >= 0x3a && c <= 0x40) || (c > 0x5a && c <= 0x60) || c > 0x7a)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe it's important to mention that `Character.isLetter` and `Character.isDigit` are also accepting characters which are not in a-z, A-Z, 0-9. For example `isDigit` is accepting all characters from Unicode category `Nd`: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm

Comment: Yes, that is the main difference between the two fastest options. Deciding between the two would depend on user requirements. But either way, they are both significantly faster than regular expressions. (Theoretically, this may be different in newer versions of java, but I doubt it.)

Comment: I would consider creating an explicit `Pattern` instead of using `String#matches(String)`. Also, maybe even create the `Matcher` outside the loop and reset it for the next input.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Good tip. I am not sure if this was an option in 2012, but I'm glad your adding this update for future people.

Comment: @Jay `Pattern` was introduced in Java 1.4 (together with `String#matches(String)`), so beginning of 2002 , but it is easy to overlook due to that convenience method on String.

Answer (score 48):

Use [String.matches()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29), like:

```
String myString = "qwerty123456";
System.out.println(myString.matches("[A-Za-z0-9]+"));
```

That may not be the absolute "fastest" possible approach.  But in general there's not much point in trying to compete with the people who write the language's "standard library" in terms of performance.

Comment: Yea. C# has a standard function for this. It appears Java does not.

Comment: But there is a point. When you are executing code in a loop millions of times, and you can make it run 5 times faster, it can make a significant impact to your message processing time, and that impacts how many servers you might need for message processing.

Comment: I believe that's overstating it. At best you're making one small aspect of the code 5 times faster. That may be worthwhile, _iff_ your performance is actually being limited by that aspect. It may well not be. For instance, if part of your message processing pipeline involves writing to a database or filesystem or doing any network comms, _that's_ likely your limiting factor. There aren't many real-world cases where speeding up a regex check by 5x will actually speed up the application by 5x (or anywhere close to 5x). And the tradeoff is less readability, flexibility, and extensibility.

Comment: ...it is important to optimize where and when it makes sense, yes.  However most of the time for most real-world applications "I made it faster by replacing a built-in, configurable, regex based function with a fixed/static loop" is not a sensible optimization.

Comment: Yes but you don’t know the context the code is being used, so you can’t judge. In this particular instance, I used this code to speed up a script that was processing gigabytes of log files, shaving 10 minutes or so off the task.

Comment: The question didn't ask for advice, it asked for the fastest solution.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex Exactly! These commentators assume that optimizing our log processing code was a waste of time. However, I was able to speed up our log processing process from over 10 minutes for one batch, to less than one minute for one batch. The change had a tangible business benefit.

Answer (score 3):

A regex will probably be quite efficient, because you would specify ranges: `[0-9a-zA-Z]`.  Assuming the implementation code for regexes is efficient, this would simply require an upper and lower bound comparison for each range.  Here's basically what a compiled regex should do:

```
boolean isAlphanumeric(String str) {
    for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if (c < 0x30 || (c >= 0x3a && c <= 0x40) || (c > 0x5a && c <= 0x60) || c > 0x7a)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I don't see how your code could be more efficient than this, because every character will need to be checked, and the comparisons couldn't really be any simpler.

Comment: Its possibly going to be between this and `String.matches()`. I was kind of hoping someone had done it before. Looks like im going to have to write the test myself (:

Comment: It all depends on the use. There is no standard way of creating the perfect algorithm for all string match scenarios. Regex may serve to a great extent, but just because it looks complex and nerdy, doesn't make it more efficient. For 100+ iterations per second, I would definitely consider a customized algorithm.