# Android How to check forcefully given string is alphanumeric or not

Tags: java, android, alphanumeric

I have tried this code. Its not working properly..

```
String myString = "343DFDFD"; // "FDFS343434"
System.out.println(myString.matches("[A-Za-z0-9]+")); //  false coming
```

note: i want output for above alphanumeric is true

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to check a string is alphanumeric in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831719/fastest-way-to-check-a-string-is-alphanumeric-in-java)

Comment: this is a true statement . what are u looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the regex as:

```
String myString = "343DFDFD"; // "FDFS343434"
System.out.println(myString.matches("^.*[^a-zA-Z0-9 ].*$")); //  false coming
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use it:

public boolean isAlphanumeric(String str) {
        for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            if (!Character.isDigit(c) && !Character.isLetter(c))
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```