# How to check if a string contains at least one alphabet char and at least one numeric char in java?

Tags: java, string

Is there any common/standard way to check if `string` contain at least one alphabetic and one numeric char. Like in this cases:

```
 checkString("AAAA") = false
 checkString("A2B2") = true
 checkString("2222") = false
```

I wanted to use [`StringUtils.isAlphanumeric()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isAlphanumeric-java.lang.CharSequence-) but in this case: `StringUtils.isAlphanumeric("AAAA")` it gives `true`.
I know that it can be written with iteration over chars, but maybe there is some other way to do this.

Comment: yes, a simple regex would do the trick

Comment: As per java doc `Returns: true if only contains letters or digits, and is non-null` http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isAlphanumeric-java.lang.CharSequence-

Comment: I'm afraid that iteration is the way to go here...

Comment: @Stultuske if you try to implement a simple RegEx you would know how complex regex could be. If performance is critical then you should avoid regex and work with the classic way over chars.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to check a string is alphanumeric in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831719/fastest-way-to-check-a-string-is-alphanumeric-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use some fancy ways to check this, like regular expressions. But I just recommend using iteration over chars for things like that.

Iteration is very easy-to-read, everyone can understand this, even junior developers who never seen Java before.

Also, a simple iteration like that is extremely fast and can be optimized with JIT-compilers.

You don't have to use a rocket launcher to kill a fly :-)

Answer (score 0):

Iteratre over each character of the string, and check for each one if it is Alpha or Numeric. You can declare two bool variables to hold the result.
Example:

```
foundAlpha = false
foundNumeric = false
```

Whenever you find a numeric or an alpha character, change the corresponding bool variable from above. Then by the end of the iterations, check if `foundAlpha && foundNumeric` is True.