# Password Verification Program Java

Tags: java

The below are the instructions and my code that I have tried so far. I am almost done but just having problems with part four. So the expected output should be:

```
Please enter a password: abc
Password much have at least 8 characters 
Please enter a password: abcd1234$
Password must only contain letter and digits
Please enter a password: ####
Password must have at least 8 characters
Password must only contain letters and digits
Please enter a password: abcd1234
Password accepted!
```

When I type *abc* this is what I get:

```
Please enter password and then hit enter:abc
Password must have at least 8 characters
Password Accepted
```

**When I do this the program ends!** Could someone help me with this?

**Problem**

> 1. Write a program that prompts the user to enter a password.
> 2. Create a boolean variable named valid and set it to true. If any of these tests below fail, set it to true.
> 3. Check the password to see if it has at least 8 characters. If it does not, display the message, "Password must have at least 8
>      characters"
> 4. Check the password to see if it consists of only letter and digits. To do this, you will need to loop through all of the characters in the
>      string. A character c is a letter of digit if this expression is true:
>
>    ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') ||
>      ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') || 
>      ('0' <= c && c <= '9')
>
> if this is even not true, break from your loop and display the
>   message, "Password must contain only letter and digits"
>   5. If valid is still true at the end of the program, display the message, "Password accepted!"

**My code**

```java
    import java.util.Scanner; 
    public class PasswordVerification {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            //Creates a scanner
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            boolean valid = false; 
            String password;


            //Asks user to enter password
            System.out.print("Please enter password and then hit enter:");
            password = sc.nextLine(); 

            //Checks to see if password is at least 8 characters. 
            if (password.length()<8) 
                {
                    valid = false;
                    System.out.println("Password must have at least 8 characters");
                }

            //Checks each character to see if it is acceptable.
            for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++){
                        char c = password.charAt(i);

                        if (       ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') // Checks if it is a lower case letter
                                || ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') //Checks if it is an upper case letter
                                || ('0' <= c && c <= '9') //Checks to see if it is a digit
                        ) 
                        {

                            valid = true;
                        } 

                        else 
                        {
                            // tells the user that only letters & digits are allowed
                            System.out.println("Only letter & digits are acceptable.");
                            valid = false;
                            break;
                        }

            }

            // if the password is valid, tell the user it's accepted
            System.out.println("Password Accepted");
            }


    }
```

Comment: Regex could be very helpful for part 4.  Is there a reason you're not using it?  Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241690/regex-for-checking-if-a-string-is-strictly-alphanumeric

Comment: you need to add a loop, a whilte for ex, and be all time in there until the password is valid

Comment: @joe Poster is clearly a complete novice. Regex is something to tackle later.

Comment: @Joe This is a Java Programming 1 class, so I only know about beginner things. And I have not heard of Regex at all so I don't know if my teacher will allow me to use it.....

Comment: Please include eception.

Comment: What do I put in the while loop? Part 3 and 4? @cralfaro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @cralfaro stated you have to repeat the process if the password is invalid:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class PasswordVerification {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //      Creates a scanner
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean valid = false; 
        String password;

        do { // start a loop
            //      Asks user to enter password
            System.out.print("Please enter password and then hit enter:");
            password = sc.nextLine(); 

            //      Checks to see if password is at least 8 characters. 
            if (password.length()<8) 
            {
                valid = false;
                System.out.println("Password must have at least 8 characters");
                continue; // skip to next iteration
            }

            //      Checks each character to see if it is acceptable.
            for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++){
                char c = password.charAt(i);

                if (       ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') // Checks if it is a lower case letter
                        || ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') //Checks if it is an upper case letter
                        || ('0' <= c && c <= '9') //Checks to see if it is a digit
                ) 
                {

                    valid = true;
                }
                else 
                {
                    // tells the user that only letters & digits are allowed
                    System.out.println("Only letter & digits are acceptable.");
                    valid = false;
                    break;
                }

            }
        } while(!valid); // verify if the password is valid, if not repeat the process

        // if the password is valid, tell the user it's accepted
        System.out.println("Password Accepted");
    }


}
```

In this way the program will continue to ask the user input if the password is not valid.

**EDIT:**
Thanks to GC_'s comment, the problem was that I missed a continue statement in the first check.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem ist this part of code:

```
if (    ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') // Checks if it is a lower case letter
     || ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') //Checks if it is an upper case letter
     || ('0' <= c && c <= '9') //Checks to see if it is a digit
    ) { valid = true; }
```

Here you reset `valid` to `true`, even if the first check with the length being less than `8` already failed.
So `abc` will fail `3.` and print `Password must have at least 8 characters` which is fine. Then it will pass `4.`, reset valid to `true` and print `Password Accepted`.

So you want the replace the `if (...) { valid = true; } else { ... }` part by

```
if (!( // if the character is none of the options below, print error
       ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') // Checks if it is a lower case letter
    || ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') //Checks if it is an upper case letter
    || ('0' <= c && c <= '9') //Checks to see if it is a digit
    )) { 
        // tells the user that only letters & digits are allowed
        System.out.println("Only letter & digits are acceptable.");
        valid = false;
        break; 
    }
```

**Edit**: 
Also you should initially set `boolean valid = true;` instead of `false`, as you want to set it to `false` only if it fails a condition.
Then at the end of your code, add a condition checking `valid` around the last output line, like

```
if(valid) {
    System.out.println("Password Accepted");
}
```

Comment: When I put this into my code, run it, and put abc as the password this is what I get:  Please enter password and then hit enter:abc
Password must have at least 8 characters
Password Accepted!

Answer (score 0):

A little messy but try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
//      Creates a scanner
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean valid = false; 
String password;


//      Asks user to enter password
while(true){
System.out.print("Please enter password and then hit enter:");
password = sc.nextLine(); 

//      Checks to see if password is at least 8 characters. 
if (password.length()<8) 
    {
        valid = false;
        System.out.println("Password must have at least 8 characters");
    }
else {

//      Checks each character to see if it is acceptable.
for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++){
            char c = password.charAt(i);

            if (       ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') // Checks if it is a lower case letter
                    || ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') //Checks if it is an upper case letter
                    || ('0' <= c && c <= '9') //Checks to see if it is a digit
            ) {
                valid = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Password denied");
                System.out.println("Only letter & digits are acceptable.");
                valid = false;
                break;
            }


}

if (valid == true) {
System.out.println("Password accepted");
    break;
        }            
}
}
}
```

Comment: This seems to be working with looping but it does not work. When I type abc it works as expected, but when I type abcd1234$ it says password accepted. But that should not be the case as it should only be accepted if it has 8 characters( which it does) and all characters are letter and digits(which is false becuase of the $)     This is the output in eclipse:                                                                  Please enter password and then hit enter:abc
Password must have at least 8 characters
Please enter password and then hit enter:abcd1234$
Password Accepted

Comment: Updated it.  Try it again

Answer (score -1):

Add a check to see if the password is still valid before printing that the password is accepted.

```
if(valid==true) {
    System.out.println("Password Accepted");
}
```

EDIT:  You can also add this.

```
else {
    System.out.println("Password Denied");
}
```

Comment: Oh he does want it in a loop.  Also, it should be valid = valid && true;

Comment: Your part is needed to.

Comment: The OP is missing the do-while loop. Your answer does not provide the correct answer and it's even counter productive.

Comment: @MuratK.  Part parts are needed, right now hid program always says pss.

Comment: @MuratK. It depends, the OP didn't ask for the do-while loop he asked why his program is printing "Password accepted" so this answer is not wrong, it is simply not the best thing to do in this case.