# Triple conditioned while loop not working

Tags: java, loops

Here is what I've done. I'm trying to have this triple conditioned while loop but it seems complete after only one of the conditions pass.

[image]

This is the console result:

[image]

Comment: Please post your code here as text

Comment: Can you add your code here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40659911/password-verification-program-java
check out this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `&&` with `||` in your while loop.

It looks like you want to prompt the user until they enter a password that meets all of three criteria. That means you need to loop as long as they *don't* meet *any* of the criteria. This calls for OR logic instead of AND (since now you only loop as long as they don't meet **all** of the criteria).