# Pick string which contains both alphabets and numbers from the following strings

Tags: java, regex, string

```
package regEx;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ReGex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] s = {"asd", "123", "123abc", "@#$", "ASSF"};
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*+$");
        for (String s1 : s) {
            Matcher m = p.matcher(s1);
            if (m.find()) {
                System.out.println(s1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And ... Any problems?

Comment: "^[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*+$" should be "^[A-Za-z0-9]+$". I recommend regex101 or similar sites to test your regexes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241690/regex-for-checking-if-a-string-is-strictly-alphanumeric
Try Above

Comment: not working. @Fildor

Comment: not enough info @ManoChandran Please read [ask] and improve question.

Comment: You have to change the title to **Pick string which contains both alphabets and numbers from the following strings**

Answer (score 2):

Why not just `s1.matches("[A-Za-z0-9]+")` instead :

```
String[] s = {"asd", "123", "123abc", "@#$", "ASSF"};
for (String s1 : s) {
    if (s1.matches("[A-Za-z0-9]+")) {
        System.out.println(s1);
    }
}
```

Your regex `^[A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*+$` not mean to match alphanumeric strings, it means :

- `^` start of string
- should start with zero or more Upper Letter `[A-Z]*`
- followed by zero or more Lower Letter `[a-z]*`
- followed by zero or more degits `[0-9]*`
- `+` i don't see why this
- `$` end of string

---

Edit

I think you mean the input should contains **both** alphabets and numbers in this case you can use this regex instead `(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)`:

```
if (s1.matches("(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)")) {
```

Comment: i got the following output:
asd
123
123abc
ASSF

Comment: and what you should to get @ManoChandran ?

Comment: @ManoChandran According to your question title, this is the desired output.

Comment: i want only the alphanumeric one. i.e. 123abc @YCF_L

Comment: @ManoChandran in this case you can use `(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)` check my edit